# Fast Fourier Transform - Plot looks strange

Tags: python, scipy, fft

The beginning of my fft plot looks strange. Any ideas why?

The data were recorded at 400 HZ.
The plot shows only the first 400 datapoints.
When I change it to e.g. *y = df['Vibra0_X'][800:1200].values*, the beginning of the plot looks the same:

```
import scipy.fftpack
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq

# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0

y = df['Vibra0_X'].head(400).values

N = len(y)
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N//2]),linestyle='-', color='blue' )

plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.title("Frequency domain of the signal", fontsize=16)


plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Is T correctly defined (assuming the data was recorded at 400 Hz)?

Or is the plot correct and just implies noise?

*I have uploaded the datapoints (1 second, 400 datapoints) to https://pastebin.com/QCCnbugL*

Comment: Your input signal probably has a large DC (0 Hz) offset. You can either subtract the mean of the signal prior to the FFT, or just ignore bin 0.

Comment: Okay thanks. Is T correctly defined with T = 1.0 / 800?

Comment: If you're sampling at 400 Hz then I would expect T to be 1 / 400.